# Reordering rows in a dataframe that follow particular sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I want to reorder rows in the following data frame if the Sequence is 2,1,3. However, this should only apply in instances where the Project ID is the same. So this logic should reorder the rows in Project 123, but should not effect Projects 124 or 125.

Here is the data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Project=c(123,123,123,124,125,125),
               Value=c(1,4,7,3,8,9),
               Sequence=c(2,1,3,2,1,3))
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
Result <- data.frame(Project=c(123,123,123,124,125,125),
                 Value=c(4,1,7,3,8,9),
                 Sequence=c(1,2,3,2,1,3))
```

Comment: Maybe this: `Data[order(Data$Project, Data$Sequence),]`.

Comment: `Data[Data$Project==123,] <- Data[Data$Project==123,][order(Data$Sequence[Data$Project==123]),]`

Answer (score 0):

Not a realy smart piece of work, but it should work - try this...
This function sorts the data rows of the specified sequence, if it appears within a project.
(you could also change the sequence)

```
reorder <- function(data, sequence=c(2,1,3)){
        seq_len <- length(sequence)
        for (i in 1:(dim(data)[1]-seq_len)){
                seq_check <- identical(sequence, data$Sequence[i:(i+seq_len-1)])
                if (seq_check) {
                        pro_check <- identical(rep(data$Project[i], seq_len), data$Project[i:(i+seq_len-1)]) #check if Project is the same over the sequence
                        if (pro_check){
                                exchange <- data[i:(i+seq_len-1),]
                                for (j in 1:seq_len){
                                        data[(i+j-1),] <- exchange[exchange$Sequence==j,]
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        data
}
```

running:

```
Data_reordered <- reorder(Data)
```

results in:

```
> Data_reordered
  Project Value Sequence
1     123     4        1
2     123     1        2
3     123     7        3
4     124     3        2
5     125     8        1
6     125     9        3
```

and:

```
> identical(Result, Data_reordered)
[1] TRUE
```

I hope that is your requested solution :-)